# App Store Review Guideline 2.5.1 - Rejection due to "Pointer Authentication API"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

Apple Store Review says they will reject our iPhone App as it contains the "**Pointer Authentication API** which is no longer appropriate under App Store Review Guideline 2.5.1".

We found this article on Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preparing_your_app_to_work_with_pointer_authentication

But don't know if it's related.  In Unity, we build our apps with Unity 2018/2019, Scripting backend IL2CPP and Target Architectures ARMv7, ARM64, and x86.

**Question:**
What is the Pointer Authentication API?  How do we remove this API to be compliant with App Store Review Guideline 2.5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the article you linked indicates, you cannot submit a app with Pointer Authentication yet.

> The App Store and TestFlight don't accept submissions containing
>   arm64e. Xcode will remove arm64e content from your app when you
>   distribute from the Organizer window. (42296212)
>   [xcode 10.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes)

Remove the arm64e architecture from your Xcode settings.
Select your iOS app target in the Project Editor, find its Architectures build setting, select the Other… option, and remove arm64e to the list of architectures.

You can also try just setting the Architecture in the unity player settings to 'Universal'
[image: Universal build settings for iOS]